# Facebook - my app permissions are not displayed in login (php)

Tags: facebook, authentication, permissions

I am using php SDK example from github:
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

As far as I understand this should open the facebook login dialog with the permissions I defined for the app, but I only see the basic permissions.

The option to check authenticated referrals is no longer available on the facebook app settings form.

Do I have to somehow request the permissions in the code itself?

Answer (score 0):

You need code, to make permission window to pop out.

Something like this shold help:

```
Do you check on user?

    // Init the Facebook SDK
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
           'appId'  => $app_id,
           'secret' => $app_secret,     
           'cookie' => true
    ));

    // Get the current user
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

if (!$user) {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => $scope,
            'redirect_uri' => $app_url,
            ));

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    }
    else{        

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

    // STUFF
    }
```

Comment: The permission window pops-up but instead of seeing the list of permissions I defined for my app on the developer app settings page, I see the list of default permissions.